# Django : Set url dynamically with <a> element in template

Tags: python, django

I'm wondering how I can change in Django this link :

```
<a href="http://localhost:8000{% url 'my-token' token=token %}">{{title}}</a>
```

I would like to set `http://localhost:8000` dynamically. If I'm working in local, it will be `http://localhost:8000` and if I am on my dev server or production server it could be `https://subdomaine.domain.com`

**My idea** :

I could create different settings file : `local.py` / `dev.py` / `prod.py` and define inside each one :

```
#local.py
SITE_URL = "http://localhost:8000"
#dev.py
SITE_URL = "http://dev.domain.com"
#prod.py
SITE_URL = "http://prod.domain.com"
```

So how I can handle my `<a>` link to add `SITE_URL` ?

Maybe with something like that `{{ request.META.HTTP_HOST }}` ?

**SOLUTION :**

You can find here the view which generate my email with Django CBV :

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    def send_email(self, email, upload, title, token):
        context = {
            'document_link': upload,
            'publication_title': title,
            'token': token,
            'MY_SITE_URL': settings.MY_SITE_URL
        }
        subject = 'my subject'
        message = get_template('emails/message.txt').render(context)
        mail = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, message, 'toto@test.eu', [email])
        html_message = get_template('emails/message.html').render(context)
        mail.attach_alternative(html_message, "text/html")
        mail.send(fail_silently=False)
```

And the message.html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<p>== This E-mail is automatically generated, please do not reply to it ==</p>

<br>

<p>Please find below your download link for the free publication:</p>

<br>

<a href="{{ MY_SITE_URL }}{% url 'freepub-token' token=token %}">{{ publication_title }}</a>

<br>

<p>You can use this link as much as you like. It will expire in 10 minutes.</p>

<br>

<p>Thank you for your interest to publications.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could send variables with a *context_processors* to any templates

Comment: @Lemayzeur So do you think it's the best idea to do that ?

Comment: @Ducky it should not be a problem. This is automatically resolved by Django. So`href="{% url 'my-token' token=token %}"` should be fine

Comment: @ruddra not in my case because it's a link situated in an email and when you click on this one, it redirects to web application/path/to/something ;)

Comment: @Ducky in your case, it is the most appropriate!

Comment: Ok I will try different methods given by SO users.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom context_processor :

```
def site(request):
    return {'SITE_URL': settings.SITE_URL}
```

Then add it to your CONTEXT_PROCESSOR setting

```
 mysite.context_processors.site,
```

and the tag {{ SITE_URL }} will be available.

Comment: I tried but up to now I don't get the expected result. I'm watching why.

Answer (score 1):

You can take care of this using context processors ([link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext)) - either by writing a custom one that make settings.SITE_URL available in every template you render.

Or, if the `request` object has the data you need, you can enable and use the built in `django.template.context_processors.request` context processor ([link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/api/#django-template-context-processors-request))

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) and [request.build_absolute_uri](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri) to get this issue done. For example:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives


def send_email(request):
    subject, from_email, to = 'hello', 'from@example.com', 'to@example.com'
    text_content = 'This is an important message.'
    url_val = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('my-token', args=['token']))
    html_content = '<p>This is an <strong>important</strong> message.</p>. <a>{}</a>'.format(url_val)  # or pass url_val as context to email template
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    msg.send()
```

#### Update

How about

```
<a href="{{ request.get_host }}{% url 'my-token' token=token %}"
```

Comment: Thank you @ruddra, but it's a bit more complicated because it takes account specific url inside the email. It should be easier with `context_processors` but I haven't no idea why it odesn't work.

Comment: @Ducky can you check my update part of the question please?

Comment: It doesn't work too :/ My url `my-token` is `app/download/token/470fe98962a9890e67dbf6df8d632439f5d5f92b/` and I have to add before `http://localhost:8000/` if I am working in local or `https://dev.domain.com` if I work on dev server etc ... Because it's a link inside an email and when you click on it, user has to be redirect to this url.

Comment: @Ducky can you please update the question with email sending related codes, like how are you generating the template for email and how are you passing it to `send_email` method.

Comment: I found, I had to add `MY_SITE_URL` in my context directly inside the view.

Comment: @Ducky please pass `'request':self.request` as context to your current template, and please see if the solution in **update** section works or not :) ?

Answer (score 0):

CLARIFICATION:
You could set the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` variable differently in each of your settings files (local.py, dev.py, prod.py).  You could then follow the below instructions to get the hostname into your template context for rendering.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

I'm doing this very thing from a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors):

`hostname = request.META.get('SERVER_NAME')`

and then return hostname from the context processor.

A bit more:  You can see more about request.META, including how to get the port number if you need it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META), and if you need to determine whether it's http or https, just use [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.scheme).

Comment: I don't want the hostname. It's not my question.

Comment: Please see the clarification just posted.  I think Django's ALLOWED_HOSTS would serve your purpose without having to define your own SITE_URL.  Also, isn't the hostname what you're actually wanting to render in the <a> tag?  You also showed the protocol and the port number in your examples - that's why I included the extra information about finding these items.